# Black hole: Infalling matter vs. increase of event horizon

Tags: black-holes, reference-frames, event-horizon, observers

Suppose we have a non-rotating, non-charged black hole and a stationary observer that is not moving relative to the black hole, and some object is falling radially into the black hole.

As far as I understand, from the perspective of such an observer, the object will never cross the event horizon.  Instead, as it comes close to the horizon, the object will appear to be smeared out over the entire horizon but never cross it.

In addition, the object will add some mass to the black hole, hence the mass of the black hole and also it's event horizon / Schwarzschild radius will increase.

Does this mean that for such an observer, the object *does* actually disappear behind the horizon because the black hole is growing?

Comment: If the observer is not falling with the object they will never observe the object crossing

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that? Because the mass of the object is not to be neglected (the black hole will grow due to the added mass), I'd expect that the exact process is rather complicated and is only accessible by means of numerical simulations?

Comment: I'm just making a point but I'll try to make it another way. The radius of the apparent horizon will double as the mass doubles but an important factor here is time-dilation. An observer some distance away will see time move more slowly at the horizon. Time will appear to move so slowly that the observer will never see the matter cross the horizon. The observer will never see the horizon grow since they don't see the matter cross.

Comment: BTW, the infalling object won't appear to the stationary observer to be smeared out. It will appear to slow down as it approaches the horizon, the light from it will get severely redshifted, and very quickly it will be too dim to detect.

Comment: There is some difference between _measuring_ (what happens where and when in the chosen coordinate chart) and _seeing_, _observing_ or how something _appears_ to you (what reaches the eye of the observer).  Due to bending of light, a compact object close to a BH or just behind it could be seen as several Einstein rings (amongst maybe other artifacts).  In Schwarzschild coordinates however (or any other sane coordinate chart for that matter) , the object is still simply connected.  Unfortunately, language is sloppy and _measuring_ and _observing_ are often used interchangeably...